# De Méré's Paradox - Probability of getting at least a "six" with 4 throws

Tags: probability

I was reading about De Mere's paradox examples, where he incorrectly assumed that the probability of getting at least a  "6" by throwing a dice 4 times is 4(1/6) = 4/6

However, when I was looking at the solutions to the problem, almost all suggest the solution to be 1-(5/6)^4 .

Now, I understand that this is mainly finding the probability of NOT getting a "6" and subtracting in from 1.

But wouldn't it be simpler to just use (1/6)^4 as this made more sense to me as the chance of getting "6" in each  throw is 1/6. Repeating it for 4 times would simply be (1/6)^4 ? I kept having the feeling that I'm missing something here.

Would really appreciate it if someone can enlighten me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Which axioms of probability are you using in your alternative calculation?  Once you answer that, it should help you determine what the calculation *really* computes.

Comment: Hi, sorry but do you mind to elaborate more on that? Axioms of probability?

Comment: What whuber is saying is that you have to evaluate what the sample space $\Omega$ is.

Comment: What you suggest is certainly a *simpler* calculation, but it's wrong. What whuber is saying is that with probability there is a minimal set of (uncontroversial) "basic facts" about it that we all take to be true as a starting point. Mathematicians call these *axioms*. There's one set of probability axioms mentioned [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbabilityAxioms.html) for example.

Comment: The axioms of probability are the rules that permit you to calculate with probabilities.  If you cannot justify your calculation using these rules, then you're just guessing--and are likely wrong.  The rules are extremely simple and small in number, so they are the first things you should learn and you should always seek to identify which ones are used in any calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with what you're calculating - you're making a leap that looks very simple but is actually the wrong calculation.

I find it helpful to write out the probability that I want to find.

$$P(\text{roll at least one 6 in four rolls}) = P(\text{roll a 6 on roll 1 or roll 2 or roll 3 or roll 4})$$

You can then use basic probability rules to evaluate the probability above by breaking the *or* statements into something easier to calculate.  This may be complicated to do directly - finding the probability that you roll one 6 or two 6s or three 6s or four 6s leaves a lot of room for simple errors.  It is much easier to take the complement by calculating the probability that you get zero 6s and then subtract this quantity from 1, like the author wrote in the solutions.

What you're calculating in your post is the probability of rolling a 6 on *every* roll - not on at least one roll.  This is where you'll want to be careful and where writing the probabilities out (starting with what you want to find) can be helpful.